# Deliver SMS messages to Danish numbers which are roaming on foreign networks

Tags: sms, bulksms, sms-gateway

I'm searching for a SMS gateway to deliver SMS messages to Danish numbers which are roaming on networks in USA and other countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Danish provider e-mail address.
For example to send SMS to Bell mobility user is required to use:

```
[10digitnumber]@txt.bell.ca (Bell and Solo)
```

Comment: I need a gateway supplier which can deliver the messages to the correct networks..

Answer (score 0):

Twilio supports sending to Danish numbers http://www.twilio.com/sms/international Be sure to read the FAQ though.

[Full disclosure: I work for Twilio]

Comment: Thank yoy very much! I have sent you an e-mail. I look forward to hearing from you as soon as possible! :)

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that, as long as you find a service which allows you to send sms messages to the Danish networks, it should not matter if your recipients are currently roaming abroad or using their phones inside the country. This consideration should be abstracted from you by the mobile phone companies.

Comment: No it isn't current, sorry. I have tried with 3 suppliers and they cannot deliver the messages to my Danish test phones which are roaming on networks in USA.

Answer (score 0):

bibob.dk has a webservice which can send sms to danish numbers. Bibob is a phone service company, so if a normal cell phone can send sms to amerika, bibob should also be able to. Of course you need to buy a sim card to use the service.

Comment: you could just buy a sim card. They are kr. 150,-

Answer (score 0):

www.openmarket.com through MXTelecom (Which was acquired by OpenMarket)